# Unable to uninstall Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, uninstallation

I seem to be unable to uninstall Anaconda from my computer.

1. I performed the uninstall in the control panel. And it is no longer in my programs and features.
2. I executed file "Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe"
3. I performed the following on Anaconda Prompt
   conda install anaconda-clean
   anaconda-clean

However, I am still able to launch and run Anaconda, Spyder, Jupyter etc.

I tried installing Anaconda again, resulting in another Anaconda installed like a duplicate (pic 1). I performed all uninstall steps. However, only the newer one is able to be removed.

Any advice?

screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHYNV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Gfa.png

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try anaconda clean before using Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe.

please read the instructions from here before doing anything: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

I had a similar case , and anaconda clean help me to remove everything.

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean
```

There is a **risky** and long way that I will not suggest.  1- uninstall everything about python 2- delete everything about Anaconda 3- delete everything about python & anaconda from registry ( high**RISK** )

Answer (score 0):

You will solve the problem by running the uninstaller as administrator.

Answer (score -2):

Try uninstalling from the control panel:
Go to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and find anaconda.Right click and uninstall.